# What is the correct way to edit a c++ project file in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I am developing a Visual Studio 2015 extension that needs to add msbuild imports to a loaded project.  I can get the path to the project file just fine but it is loaded in a private Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection controlled by an assembly in the PrivateAssemblies Visual Studio folder.  Is there any way to get access to the Microsoft.Build object via a public API?

Comment: I not sure what is public API, is it a DLL project?

Comment: Do you resolve the issue, if the issue still exists, please feel free let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click reference -> add reference -> extensions -> check Microsoft.Build -> OK, then you could use it like this:

```
System::String^ projectPath = L"D:\\Project\\Msbuild\\TestProject\\CppConsoleApp\\CppConsoleApp.vcxproj";
    Project^ project = gcnew Project(projectPath);
```